# PostgreSQL update a table from another one joined as many to many

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, left-join

I have three tables: `user`, `image` and `user_images_image` (cos the first two related as ManyToMany). I would like to set the `profile_pic` of the `user` table to the value of the `name` property taken from the `image` table.

I know how to build a `SELECT` query for something like this but it's not very helpful...
I would write something like this:

```
SELECT "user".id, image.name FROM "user"
LEFT JOIN user_images_image uii ON "user".id = uii."userId"
LEFT JOIN image ON uii."imageId" = image."id"
WHERE "user".id = 2;
```

In PostgreSQL I can't just join two tables the way I would in MySQL.

How do I write such a query?

Comment: If you have a many-to-many relationship between `user` and `image`, then you can potentially retrieve more than one `image.name` per `user.id`.  This cannot be fed into an `update` without reducing it to only one `image.name` per `user.id`.  What is it that you want if there is more than one `image.name` per `user.id`?

Comment: Mmm yeah I also have an image.id, so basically I'm making an update for user.id = <USER_ID> and image.id = <IMAGE_ID>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Postgres, you would use the update/join syntax as follows:

```
update "user" u
set profile_pic = i.name
from user_images_image uii
inner join image i on uii."imageId" = i."id"
where uii."userId" = u.id and u.id = ? and i.id = ?
```

If there are no missing images, then an alternative is a correlated subquery:

```
update "user" u
set profile_pic = (
    select i.name
    from user_images_image uii
    inner join image i on uii."imageId" = i."id"
    where uii."userId" = u.id and i.id = ?
) 
where u.id = ?
```

Comment: Oh sorry, I missed something,  I also have an image.id, so basically I'm making an update for user.id = <USER_ID> and image.id = <IMAGE_ID>.

Comment: @Albert: ok, this makes more sense. I modified the queries accordingly.

Comment: Thank you and as far as I understand it should be `i."id"` in `inner join image i on uii."imageId" = image."id"`. If corrected it works the expected way.

Comment: I know technically it's not related but here's a strange thing...like I said, it works as expected when I execute it with the help of my DB client and it just hangs and never terminates when executed as a raw query with typeorm. May it be because of some syntax issue? I'm just clueless...I even asked another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63478175/a-raw-postgresql-query-hangs-when-executed-with-typeorm