# A raw PostgreSQL query hangs when executed with TypeOrm

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sql-update, typeorm

I'm making this update query:

```
await this.userRepository.query(
    `
        update "user" u
        set profile_pic = i.name
        from user_images_image uii
        inner join image i on uii."imageId" = i."id"
        where uii."userId" = u.id and u.id = ${userId} and i.id = ${imageId};
    `,
);
```

And it just does not terminate even though I execute the same query in my DB client and it works as expected.

Comment: What the `pg_stat_activity` is saying? What's the state of the connection?

Comment: @GustavoKawamoto The `pg_stat_activity` says that it's a lock and namely `wait_event_type` is lock, `wait_event` is transactionid and `state` is active. Is that the connection state you're asking about?

Comment: Yup. By the looks of it, there's something locking your update somehow. You can find what's locking what by using [these queries](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring).

Comment: @GustavoKawamoto Oh thank you, I will check them out. But as I've just managed to find out it has something to do with the transaction I'm making, well to be more accurate, I've rewritten the same method without making a transaction and it works...

Comment: @GustavoKawamoto Do you have any ideas on what that transactionid might be? It's not very clear to me how it works on the low-level.

Comment: Got very curious about what was locking your query and if it was something caused by typeorm. Would you mind sharing the output from the second query in a pastebin? This surely isn't a expected behaviour.

Comment: PostgreSQL was waiting for other transaction to finish it's work using whatever shared resources it was using (records, table, whatever was being shared between the two transactions). That's why it was locking. But unless you've got other methods doing transactions in these two tables, it shouldn't be blocking (and typeorm definitely shouldn't be blocking as well, since it's a simple update).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220059/discussion-between-gustavo-kawamoto-and-albert).

Comment: @GustavoKawamoto sure I don't mind, but I don't quite understand what you mean by the second query =( mmm I've never used pastebin though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a troubleshooting session we found out that the query was being locked because another connection was trying to update a related resource (a record in a `users` table with a foreign key from `user_images_image`) for a different transaction in the same method, both awaiting it's results to commit.

By using the same connection we ended up with the right behaviour.

We found that out by using the Lock monitoring query [from the docs](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring):

```
SELECT blocked_locks.pid     AS blocked_pid,
         blocked_activity.usename  AS blocked_user,
         blocking_locks.pid     AS blocking_pid,
         blocking_activity.usename AS blocking_user,
         blocked_activity.query    AS blocked_statement,
         blocking_activity.query   AS current_statement_in_blocking_process,
         blocked_activity.application_name AS blocked_application,
         blocking_activity.application_name AS blocking_application
   FROM  pg_catalog.pg_locks         blocked_locks
    JOIN pg_catalog.pg_stat_activity blocked_activity  ON blocked_activity.pid = blocked_locks.pid
    JOIN pg_catalog.pg_locks         blocking_locks 
        ON blocking_locks.locktype = blocked_locks.locktype
        AND blocking_locks.DATABASE IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.DATABASE
        AND blocking_locks.relation IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.relation
        AND blocking_locks.page IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.page
        AND blocking_locks.tuple IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.tuple
        AND blocking_locks.virtualxid IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.virtualxid
        AND blocking_locks.transactionid IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.transactionid
        AND blocking_locks.classid IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.classid
        AND blocking_locks.objid IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.objid
        AND blocking_locks.objsubid IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.objsubid
        AND blocking_locks.pid != blocked_locks.pid
 
    JOIN pg_catalog.pg_stat_activity blocking_activity ON blocking_activity.pid = blocking_locks.pid
   WHERE NOT blocked_locks.GRANTED;
```